# Household API not returning my household on my friends phone

Tags: sonos

I'd like to write an app that lets friends, who visit my place, control my devices using the Sonos API.

My friend is connected to my Sonos home (connect to the same wifi, open Sonos app, select "Connect to an existing system").

The [household API](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/households/) only returns my friend's existing household, but not mine. This means that he can't query the groups or perform any playback/start/pause operation using the Sonos API.

Is there any way my friend would be able to control my devices using the Sonos APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a user authorizes an app to access their Sonos account, only that user's household(s) are visible to that app. The fact that the user is on another Sonos owner's LAN is not relevant, as all communication goes through the cloud.

The only way for user A to access user B's household is for user B to login to user A's app themselves.

Comment: If my friend is connected to my existing system and opens the Sonos app, they have access to my music services and can start and control playback. How would you build something similar using the Sonos APIs?

The only (terrible!) workaround I can think of is to share the OAuth token between people connected to the same wifi.

Comment: The Sonos App is operating on the LAN, and doesn’t use the same authentication mechanism as our open platform. There’s no way to do what you want to do, and that’s by design. You can, of course, log in the the integration with your credentials, thereby giving your friend access to your household.